# When build VTK: error: no match for ‘operator<<’

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, vtk

I am trying to install vtk-6.0.0 on a Kubuntu VIRTUAL machine. After I managed to run the make command after instroducing simple changes int he vtk configure and make files, the make build stopped wit hte following message:

```
In file included from /home/mazen/Desktop/VTK/VTK_6.0.0/VTK-6.0.0/Common/Core/vtkObject.h:43:0,
                 from /home/mazen/Desktop/VTK/VTK_6.0.0/VTK-6.0.0/Rendering/Core/vtkGenericVertexAttributeMapping.h:29,
                 from /home/mazen/Desktop/VTK/VTK_6.0.0/VTK-6.0.0/Rendering/Core/vtkGenericVertexAttributeMapping.cxx:15:
/home/mazen/Desktop/VTK/VTK_6.0.0/VTK-6.0.0/Rendering/Core/vtkGenericVertexAttributeMapping.cxx: In member function ‘void vtkGenericVertexAttributeMapping::AddMapping(int, const char*, int, int)’:
/home/mazen/Desktop/VTK/VTK_6.0.0/VTK-6.0.0/Rendering/Core/vtkGenericVertexAttributeMapping.cxx:89:7: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘vtkOStreamWrapper’ and ‘std::ostringstream {aka std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>}’)
       << attributeName);
/home/mazen/Desktop/VTK/VTK_6.0.0/VTK-6.0.0/Common/Core/vtkSetGet.h:509:22: note: in definition of macro ‘vtkWarningWithObjectMacro’
             << "): " x << "\n\n";                               \
                      ^
/home/mazen/Desktop/VTK/VTK_6.0.0/VTK-6.0.0/Rendering/Core/vtkGenericVertexAttributeMapping.cxx:88:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘vtkWarningMacro’
     vtkWarningMacro("Replacing existing mapping for attribute "
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I was not able to understand what is missing for the compiler to break with these messages.

I have dumped the make output to a log file which can be accessed through [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnzgxdtxmau5hh7/log?dl=0). Things are clearer now with a `no match for ‘operator<<’` message on `Line 39`. However, the code must be correct because it is the original vtk code and no changes are introduced here.

Many thanks to you in advance

Comment: Probably there are compiler errors earlier in the output that are the real issue, and then make is just reporting that the compilation process failed.

Comment: @Mazen: Without build message describing the exact error we cannot help you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have updated the question and posted a link to the log file dumped from the `make` command. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mazen: I have pasted into the question post the first error message from the log you link to. Next time you will ask about problems while building something, you should do such things by yourself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Many thianks to you and my apologies to you and the community if what I have done is a blatant breach to the rules. I would have thought that it would be okay to do that since there is a link facility in the posting window and it is common practice on other sub-forums such as TeX stackexchange. Sincerely,

Comment: Following up the point at which the compiler breaks, I found out that the problem comes from the following expression `vtkWarningMacro ("Replacing exsisting mapping for attribute ") << atrtributeName);`. Other posts suggest retyping this piece of code but I CANNOT do that because it is a working code on other platforms and the problem could be due to misintrepretation by the compiler. (a sheer guess that a missing option could simply do the trick)

Comment: A correction to the previous piece of code. There is an extra paranthesis and the correct code is `vtkWarningMacro ("Replacing exsisting mapping for attribute " << attributeName);`

Comment: I have managed to solve th problem. Although in a crude way but at least there is enough reasoning why it did not work with the build of vtk-6.0. I will update you with the -phony solution- I have found when I get back to office.